# Why does this bubble sort leave 2 elements in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

I translated this code from a pseudo code example of the bubble sort algorithm, but when I implement it, it returns 2 values in the wrong place.

Here's the code:

```js
var numbers = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var swapMade;
var temp;

function setup() {
  swapMade = true;
  
  while (swapMade == true) {
    swapMade = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length - 2 ; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
        numbers[i+1] = temp;
        swapMade = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers));
}

setup();
```

This returns:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1]
```

So `10` and `1` are in the wrong place.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: `i < numbers.length - 2`

Comment: It's either `i < numbers.length - 1` or `i <= numbers.length - 2`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `i < numbers.length - 2` to `i < numbers.length - 1` in your for-loop.

With `i < numbers.length - 2` your loop will quit before evaluating the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate until the index is equal to `numbers.length - 1`. Currently, you are not comparing the second last element at index `numbers.length - 2` with the last element since you stop right before `numbers.length - 2`.

```js
var numbers = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var swapMade;
var temp;

function setup() {
  swapMade = true;
  
  while (swapMade) {
    swapMade = false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1 ; i++) {
      if (numbers[i] > numbers[i+1]) {
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
        numbers[i+1] = temp;
        swapMade = true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers));
}

setup();
```

Answer (score 0):

the code lacks one more iteration due to `i < numbers.length -2`

try changing that to `i < numbers.length - 1` to fix it.

`i < numbers.length - 1` will go from the first index (0) upto the second to the last index to account for the `i+1`